# how can extract the name from a line

Tags: c++

Assume that I have a line from a file that I want to read:

```
>NZ_FNBK01000055.1 Halorientalis regularis
```

So how can extract the name from that line that begins with a greater than sign; everything following the greater-than sign (and excluding the newline at the end of the line) is the name.
The name should be:

```
NZ_FNBK01000055.1 Halorientalis regularis
```

Here is my code so far:

```
bool file::load(istream& file)
{
string line;
while(getline(genomeSource, line)){
    if(line.find(">") != string::npos)
    {
        m_name = 
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: the name that I want is everthing after the '>'. How can I get the name without '>'? like m_name = the name or cout<<the name?

Comment: It's time to learn the wonderful features of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Notice that thingy called `substr` for instance.

Comment: Does the > need to be at the start of the line? Your code is searching for a > anywhere in a line. If you are only interested in a > at the start of the line then the if condition should be  `line.find(">") == 0`

Answer (score 3):

You could easily handle both conditions using *regular expressions*. c++ introduced [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) in c++11. Using this and a regex like:

```
>.*? (.*?) .*$
```

- `>` Get the literal character
- `.*?` Non greedy search for anything stopping at a space
  `(.*?)` Non greedy search sor anything stopping at a space but grouping the characters before hand.
- `.*$` Greedy search until the end of the string.

With this you can easily check if this line meets your criteria *and* get the name at the same time. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/27WYOI/1) is a test showing it working. For the code, the c++11 regex lib is very simple:

```
std::string s = ">NZ_FNBK01000055.1 Halorientalis regularis    "; 
std::regex rgx(">.*? (.*?) .*$"); // Make the regex
std::smatch matches;

if(std::regex_search(s, matches, rgx)) { // Do a search
    if (matches.size() > 1) { // If there are matches, print them.
        std::cout << "The name is " << matches[1].str() << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/4bSMSs) is a live example.